# Is this an appropriate place to ask curriculum planning questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm planning the curriculum for my first graduate level computer science course. Are questions related to appropriate expectations for incoming knowledge and course coverage allowed here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that such a question could be entirely within scope.  Some key information to include in order to make it clear enough to be answered would include:

- What country you are in
- What sort of graduate program (e.g., M.S., Ph.D.)
- What level of institution (e.g., world-class research university, vocational college)
- What the general goals of the course are

Comment: Thanks, glad to know I wouldn't be totally off track here.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about how to plan curricula in general are fine: planning curricula is an important thing that happens in academia. Questions about what the curriculum for a particular course should be would be off-topic, since you'd be asking about (in this case) computer science, rather than about academia.